# How to actually make persistent connection between php application, maxscale and RDS

Tags: php, proxy, rds, maxscale

I need to create persistent connection between my application, MaxScale and RDS. When load is around 40K MaxScale stops finding master and send all connections to Slave for no reason.

I am using mysql pconnect and maxscale persistent connection together. Any lead will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using persistent connections between the client app and MaxScale, there is no need to enable persistent connections between MaxScale and the database as the connections in the client's connection pool will be kept open as long as they are valid.

From MaxScale's point of view, pooled client connections will simply appear as very long client sessions. This gives a minuscule improvement in performance and memory use as the persistent connection mechanism in MaxScale isn't in use.

As for the connection problems, the first step into diagnosing problems with MaxScale is to inspect the log files for errors. If this yields no results, I'd suggest opening a bug report on the [MaxScale Jira](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MXS).